# Is there a way to add items to the native browser's context menu from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, contextmenu, chromium

Trying to implement context menus for websites is, at least in my experience, difficult. I primarily build single page applications using react, where often a context menu is a necessity. Although to this day, I have not found a good context menu library on npm. My current library of choice is [react menu](https://github.com/szhsin/react-menu), which is decent but is buggy and not great for performance. All of the other context menu libraries seem to be lacking features, or have been discontinued for several years. I was wondering whether the inbuilt context menu for the browser can be manipulated by a website much like the [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus) API.

I recently discovered that chrome devtools is in fact, just an ordinary webpage, and on any chromium based browser, you can visit it here: **devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html**. And of course devtools uses custom context menus in many places, such as on the tabs.

[image]

*This screenshot was taken from ms edge, but the same happens for chrome*

So clearly, custom context menus can be implemented somehow, considering that I could reproduce this context menu in an ordinary browser tab. I am aware that devtools is running in a browser protected protocol (devtools), which may be given extra privileges to access whatever api is being used for the context menus, but I can't see why chromium would intentionally restrict the use of an api such as this.

An api such as this would be incredibly useful, and I am about to look through [the chrome devtools source code](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) to find how this is pulled off, but in the case that the api is for some reason restricted to ordinary websites, I was wondering if anyone has any idea what api is being used in devtools.

Comment: No that's not possible without an extension. That functionality is not exposed via any web-based API in any major browser.

Comment: If you go according to @Slbox 's comment, you can prompt a user to install an extension and then give them a warning on the screen saying that they won't be able to use the website to its full potential without the extension and probably make them wait for 10-20 seconds before letting them close the window and add an option from where they can install the extension whenever they want. That seems to be a good idea (at least for me it is)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the api for making a custom native context menu **does not exist**.

Firefox had an experimental/non-standard api, but that was removed again: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu

So not possible on the general web to my knowledge as of today. Though depending on your context you might have access to modifying the native context menu:

- Adding menu items via browser extensions

  - firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items
  - chromium based browsers: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/
- Electron has an api to create custom context menus: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#render-process
- I believe that the chrome dev tools use an internal api for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the current time to alter the browser's native context menu, except [through extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/).

You mentioned that you've tried context menu libraries, may I suggest (shameless plug) [my context menu library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@printy/react-context-menu)?

Comment: Hi sorry I know this is a bit late, but I was wondering if you were thinking about adding nested items support (sub menus). Honestly that and keyboard navigation are the two main things I'm looking for.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Hi, I could do that. [Let's continue the conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255423/react-context-menu-discussion)